# Out-of-bounds read: off-by-one vulnerability

Tags: c++

The following code is being flagged as a probable out of bounds read vulnerability. I don't understand how this can be an issue because the variable `value` should contain the data present in the address of the `valuePtr`. I would like to know if the code below is writing the data to `value` in an incorrect manner.

```
 long GetItemData(long Index);
 double* valuePtr = (double*) GetItemData(1);
 double value = *valuePtr;
```

Comment: If the array `GetItemData` tries to read is length-0 or length-1, then `GetItemData(1)` will be index-out-of-bounds.

Comment: why is that function returning a `long` when it should return a `double*`?

Comment: @SergeyA - flagged by security sw  like qualsys

Answer (score 0):

As a comment pointed out, what if the list is empty? What if the list has only one item in it?

On a different note, casting a long to a double* and then dereferencing it is undefined behavior in most modern C++ compilers (violates strict type-aliasing rules). And as a portability concern, 'long' is not necessarily the same size as 'double*'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code may be in an incorrect manner.

Converting integer to pointer is implementation-defined and if pointer requires more memory than `long` -- for example, `sizeof(long)=4, sizeof(double*)=8` -- The conversion will lead to dropping some information and it may lead to Segmentation Fault.

To pass pointers, you should use correct pointer types.

I don't know if there will be out-of-bounds error because I do bot know the implementation of `GetItemData()`.

Comment: I believe it's actually undefined behavior at the point where he dereferences it, by the strict aliasing rule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/5557309